# how to populate previous value till new value is populated

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have below Set of data where Count is calculated for each month. 
I have to create a report with this data but the count we get for each month around 5th or 6th business day. Till then it always shows NULL or 0. 
so, I would like to populate previous value till we get the count for the months.

so, if below is my data set, then I would like to see the count 14793417 for the months >='2018-08-01'. As soon as we get the data for these months then it should pull in the right count and not previous count.

```
Count       yyyymm  Month-Date
15339017    201801  2018-01-01
13832952    201802  2018-02-01
14432701    201803  2018-03-01
14259210    201804  2018-04-01
14863942    201805  2018-05-01
14377470    201806  2018-06-01
14793417    201807  2018-07-01
NULL        NULL    2018-08-01
NULL        NULL    2018-09-01
NULL        NULL    2018-10-01
NULL        NULL    2018-11-01
NULL        NULL    2018-12-01
```

I tried with lag function but i am not getting it right.

```
 select distinct 
 [count],
 CASE WHEN [count] IS NULL THEN 
lag([count]) over(partition by [Month-Date])  order by [Month-Date])
else [count] end,
yyyymm
from #table
group by [Month-Date],yyyymm
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your `#table`, but below is the example:

```
WITH ABC 
AS
(
   SELECT 1 as month, 500 as total
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 1000
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3, NULL
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 4 , NULL
)
SELECT month,ISNULL(total,previousMonth)
FROM 
(
   SELECT *, LAG(TOTAL)OVER(ORDER BY month) as previousMonth
   FROM ABC
) as A
```